# Cmake does not make sln files (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am struggling to generate `*.sln` file using CMake, but unfortunately I get the error message shown below. Note that the `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp` and `CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj` files exist in the mentioned folders.
I have Universal Windows Platform development and Desktop development with C++ installed and I also tried running the script as Administrator.

The command is as follows: cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" .

Thank you in advance.

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/8/2018 2:30:02 PM.
Project "C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp': No such file or directory [C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp': No such file or directory [C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.61


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/8/2018 2:30:05 PM.
Project "C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp': No such file or directory [C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp': No such file or directory [C:\projects\EuropeanCoDiOptimization\dispatching\src\CMakeFiles\3.12.3\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.65
```

Comment: This looks like you are building cmake targets, not generating solution. Also it is not clear why would you want to generate solution since you already have vcxproj.

Comment: @VTT: File `CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj` is a *temporary* solution for check a compiler. It is not a solution for the main project.

Comment: @VeGh: Please, provide the code in the `CMakeLists.txt` file which *precedes* the `project()` call.

Comment: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# add "external/CppUtils/cmake" directory to include path of CMake

set(module_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/CppUtils/cmake")

list(INSERT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 0 "${module_dir}")

some other includes follow

Comment: btw, I have Universal Windows Platform development and Desktop development with C++ installed.

Comment: You should add this into question, not into comment. Also you should provide command line you've used for cmake. If I remember correctly, project generation is not supposed to check for compilers or build anything.

Comment: @VTT, compiler check is obligatory for generating resulting files. It is the first step cmake does so it could determine if everything for the building is available.

Comment: @ixSci Why would project generation alone (without build) trigger compiler availability checks? Or did they break stand-alone project generation only in recent releases (by introducing unskippable feature checks for example)?

Comment: @VTT, it is required because CMake sets some variables (like ptr size and other stuff) based on the compiler available and it checks for it in the very first step. These checks have been there since forever, I guess. At least for the last 8 years it has been working that way.